# i need jquery code for converting date format without external js library

Tags: javascript, jquery

i need jquery/javascript code for converting date format without exteranl js library. below is the example

i need to convert from FORMAT 1 to FORMAT 2

```
FORMAT 1: Wed Apr 20 07:05:00 PDT 2016 
FORMAT 2: 2016-04-20 07:23:42.476
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you make some research?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var todayDate=new Date("Wed Apr 20 07:05:00 PDT 2016 ");
  var format ="AM";
  var hour=todayDate.getHours();
  var min=todayDate.getMinutes();
  var sec = todayDate.getSeconds();
  if(hour>11){format="PM";}
  if (hour   > 12) { hour = hour - 12; }
  if (hour   == 0) { hour = 12; }  
  if (min < 10){min = "0" + min;}
  document.write(todayDate.getFullYear() + "-" +(todayDate.getMonth()+1) + "-" + todayDate.getDate() + "  " +  hour+":"+min+":"+sec+" "+format);
```